# removing/toggling CSS class from extjs 4.2 button

Tags: css, extjs4.2

Is there any working example of toggling or removing CSS class from ExtJS 4.2 component, xtype: button in particular? 
I have found and tried a method from API, but no effect. If the method is working for you, would you explain what I did wrong?

```
    button.removeCls("sample-button-over");
```

Comment: I think I got it conceptually wrong. API does work, sorry about that. So "base" css gets removed, but "button-over-state" is not getting removed. So the idea as follows, if button is in the pressed state, I want it to not to be highlighted on mouse hover.

Comment: I have found an elegant way without deleting classes. .personalcabinetbutton-pressed.personalcabinetbutton-over{
    background-image: url(../images/bnd-portal/25x25/personal-cabinet-bright-pink-25x25.png) !important;
} This way, I am "overriding" for time being .personalcabinetbutton-over class, and a pressed button is not highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add both **mouseover** and **mouseout** eventsto button. On mouseover, check the condition whether it is pressed or not, if not pressed add the CSS class, and remove the class on mouseout. It should work

Comment: Thank you. I will try your suggestion in order to check the answer as accepted.